# Error installing taps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, taps

Here is my Gem Environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/haonanzhang/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

I want to install taps to export a database from Heroku.

But when I run sudo gem install taps, I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing taps:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from extconf.rb:3
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on superuser or serverfault, as it is not a programming question but rather an installation question.

Comment: Which version of taps? I just tried a `heroku db:pull` and it worked fine for me. I have taps `0.3.11` installed, the same version of Ruby and RubyGems 1.3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same exact error after my mac crashed. I didn't want to use win so I loaded [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) on my win box and got everything up and going in 5 hours.

You need to go into readline and execute a make file. I also highly suggest you use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your gems and ruby versions. You can switch between gems and versions which you will probably need to do in this exact scenario .

1. cd ruby/version/ext/redline
2. ruby extconf.rb
3. make
4. sudo make install

Make sure you replace `version` with your ruby version and fill in the appropriate path for ruby.

Another known issue and this is the ruby version which is why [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) is a wonderful resource to switch between gem and ruby versions. ruby 1.9.1 has problems with taps and AFAIK Ubuntu, possible other OSs too.

After I ran the make file as explained above I had to switch ruby version to 1.8.7 to get taps to pull the data from herkou and then switch back to 1.9.1 for development. I never had this problem on mac FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```